# Laravel Edit form error

Tags: php, laravel

this is my form:

```
{!! Form::model($countries, ['route' => ['countries.update', $countries->id], 'method' => "PUT"]) !!}
   {{ Form::label('code', 'Country Code:') }}
   {{ Form::text('code', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
   {{ Form::label('name', 'Country Name:') }}
   {{ Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
   {{ Form::submit('Save', ['class' => 'mt-20 btn btn-success btn-sm']) }}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

and this is my update function:

```
$countries = Country::find($id);
$this->validate($request, array(
   'code' => 'required|min:2|max:4',
   'name' => 'required|max:255'
));
$country = Country::where('id',$id)->first();
$country->code = Input::get('code');
$country->name = Input::get('name');
$country->save();
Session::flash('success', 'The Country info was successfully updated.');
return redirect()->route('locations.index', $country->id);
```

what is the issue in my form that I'm getting `Undefined variable: countries` error from my blade?

Comment: In the `edit` function, from where the form is getting called, you must not have passed the `$countries` variable to the form.

Comment: Also, if you are passing multiple countries, you can't say `$countries->id`.

Comment: no is just edit 1 country when they click on edit button

Comment: Show us the code for `edit` function.

Comment: @linuxartisan thanks man, I was forgotten to put `$countries = Country::find($id);` in edit function. :)

Comment: I've converted our comments to an answer. Please accept it if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consolidating this answer from our conversation in the comments.

The error `Undefined variable: countries` in the blade view (form) arises as you have forgotten to pass the said variable to the view.

In the `edit` function (as this the function calling the view), add the following

```
$countries = Country::find($id); // though I'd suggest naming it $country
...
return view('<view_name>', compact('countries'));
```